# react native store notification data when app is close or in backaground

Tags: android, ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to build a react native app that includes chat, I'm using realm for storing my data on the device, and FCM to get a remote notification with 'react-native-firebase'.

**I would like to know if there is any way that I can save the data of the remote notification to realm without entering the app or to the notification.**

I know that Whatsapp does that - even if Whatsapp app is close, when you are connected to the internet and you get a new messages or images, they saved the data to their local db.